# Get current uri in Typo3 Neos Page Template

Tags: fluid, neoscms

How can I get the current URI within a Typo3 Neos Page Template?

I tried something like `{fed:page.absoluteUrl()}`. But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
{neos:uri.node(node: node)}
```

instead.

Fx:

```
<a href="{neos:uri.node(node: node)}">Link Here</a>
```

Comment: If you want the absoluteUrl use the ViewHelper like this:

    **{neos:uri.node(node: node, absolute: true)}**